# Change case of specified characters in a string

Tags: vb.net, string, localization

I have all-one-case strings representing postal addresses stored in a database, but I want to capitalize US state abbreviations (e.g. " ca " to " CA ") when the abbreviation is separated from the rest of the string by a space on either side.

The lousy way I could do it would be to have 50 statements like

```
If addressString.Contains(" al ") Then addressString.Replace(" al ", " AL ")
If addressString.Contains(" ak ") Then addressString.Replace(" ak ", " AK ")
...
```

Edit: That is a really lousy way! Here's what I did instead:

```
addressString = StrConv(addressString, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
```

'This needed to be done anyway, but it turns " ak " into " Ak ".

```
Static stateAbbrevs As New List(Of String)(New String() {" Ak ", " Al ", " Ar "...})
    For Each a In stateAbbrevs
        If addressString.Contains(a) Then
            addressString= addressString.Replace(a, a.ToUpper)
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store them in an array i guess...

```
Dim States() as string = new string(){" al "," al "}
For i = 0 to States.Length -1
         If addressString.Contains(States(i)) Then addressString = addressString.Replace(States(i), States(i).ToUpper)
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

The real question is where to store the list of abbreviations. - in the program, in a database, in a flat or xml file.  All of these are easy to turn into a list of strings, and then iterate over that list replacing each occurence in your target string.

```
Private states as list(of string) 
Private Function CapitalizeState(ByVal addressText As String) As String
    Dim result as string = addresstext
    For each st as string in states
       result =  Replace( result,  st,   st,   CompareMethod := CompareMethod.Text)
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

Initializing the list and optimpizations are left as an exercise....